# JSON Schema for Array Selection with Exclusion of "None" Combined with Other Options

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm relatively new to JSON Schema and I'm struggling to create a schema that enforces a specific constraint on an array field. The requirement is that the array field, named "selection", can contain values "a", "b", "c", or "none". However, the array cannot contain both "none" and any of the values "a", "b", or "c" simultaneously. Here's an example to clarify:

**Valid JSONs:**

```json
{
  "selection": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

```json
{
  "selection": ["none"]
}
```

**Invalid JSON:**

```json
{
  "selection": ["a", "b", "none"]
}
```

I've tried using `oneOf` with `const` and `enum`, but I couldn't get it to work as expected. Can someone assist me in creating a JSON Schema that properly enforces this constraint?

Here's the schema I've been working with:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "selection": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "oneOf": [
                {
                  "const": "none"
                },
                {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": ["a", "b", "c"]
                }
              ]
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["selection"]
}
```

Any suggestions or corrections to this schema would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this, but it requires draft2020-12 to support prefixItems if you want to support just a single entry of `none` in the array.

You need [`unevaluatedItems`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array#unevaluateditems) which, when set to `false` allows the presence of `none` in the first `oneOf` schema that contains the enum causes it to not match.

If you want `none` to be the only entry in the array when it exists, you'll also need [`prefixItems`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array#tupleValidation). Although you could probably get away with `maxItems:1` as well.

It depends on how strict you want to be with your required format:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "selection": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["a", "b", "c"]
          },
          "unevaluatedItems": false
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "prefixItems": [
            {
              "const": "none"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": ["selection"]
}
```

```
// Passes:
{ selection: ["none"] }
{ selection: ["a","b","c"] }

// Fails
{ selection: ["a","b","none"] }
```

[Vitest stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-xke9jd?file=package.json,test%2Fbasic.test.ts,src%2Fvalidator.ts&initialPath=__vitest__/)

Comment: Thanks, Adam.  I am trying to stick with draft-07 but will keep your solution in my notebook.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use draft-04 - draft-2019-09, you can use this syntax:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "selection": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "enum": [
                            "a",
                            "b",
                            "c"
                        ]
                    },
                    "additionalItems": false
                },
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "const": "none"
                        }
                    ],
                    "additionalItems": false
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "selection"
    ]
}
```

OR

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "selection": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "enum": [
                            "a",
                            "b",
                            "c"
                        ]
                    },
                    "additionalItems": false
                },
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                       "const": "none"
                    },
                    "maxItems": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "selection"
    ]
}
```

The error messages are quite similar so either will work.

Versions of JSON Schema prior to 2020-12 allowed the use of `items: []` to indicate a tuple-like ordered index of values.

The first example shows this pattern and uses `additionalItems: false` to prevent any other items to be added to the array.

#### valid

- `{"selection": ["none"]}`
- `{"selection": ["a","a","a"]}`
- `{"selection": ["a"]}`
- `{"selection": ["a","b"]}`
- etc...

#### invalid

- `{"selection": ["a","a","none"]}`
- `{"selection": ["none", "none"]}`

The second example uses `maxItems` and `items: {}` (object) where the index value can only be `const: "none"` and `maxItems: 1` prevents any further indices to be populated.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy.  Your solution works.  I also added uniqueItems.